# Show that $IntA $ is the largest open set contained in $A\subset \Bbb R.$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $IntA $ is the largest open set contained in $A\subset \Bbb R.$

We first, try to prove that $Int A$ is open. We define $$IntA=\{x\in A:\exists \epsilon \gt 0, V_{\epsilon}(x)\subset A\}.$$ If $x\in Int A$ then, from definition we have, that $\exists V_{\epsilon}(x)\subset  A.$ This means that, $\forall a\in V_{\epsilon}(x)$, $\exists \epsilon'\gt 0$ such that, $V_{\epsilon'}(a)\subset A.$ Hence,  $a\in Int A,$ then $V_{\epsilon}(x)\subset A\implies Int A$ is an open set.

Now, we proceed to prove that $Int A$ is the largest open subset of $A.$ If $B$ is any other open subset of $A$ then it means that $\forall b\in B,$ there exists an $\epsilon $ neighborhood in $B$ such that $V_{\epsilon}(b)\subset A.$ But this means that $b\in Int A$ from the definition of $Int A.$ So, $B\subset Int A.$ This completes the proof.

---

However, I am doubtful whether my proof is correct ? Can anyone, please validate my answer? The thing is, the notion of $Int A$ was known to me, only intuitively, by the idea that " it consists all the interior points of $A",$ and nothing else. But while solving this question, I found the definition , of $Int A$ i.e   $IntA=\{x\in A:\exists \epsilon \gt 0, V_{\epsilon}(x)\subset A\},$ while browsing through various resources. So, this is my first time, working with $Int A$ formally. So, I need a little help in judging whether my approach to the problem and my idea about the set  $Int A$ is correct or not?

Comment: It is correct._

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for your confirmation! I got the confidence I needed.

Comment: @AnneBauval Fixed it.

Comment: Here is a duplicate, in the more general context of metric spaces: [Showing that the set of interior points of a set in a metric space is the largest open set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948480/showing-that-the-set-of-interior-points-of-a-set-in-a-metric-space-is-the-larges) (the proof in the accepted answer is the same as yours)

Comment: @AnneBauval Undortunately, I have no idea about what a metric space/topological space is. Till now, the thing we are taught is, "Basic Topology in$\Bbb R$" in a real analysis course.